# linkedin fetching details in asp.net MVC

Tags: oauth, jsapi

Out of the two methods of : JS API and OAUTH ,can anyone suggests which one is more reliable and should be used?
I want user to come on my application and from there I want them to login in LinkedIn from where all his personal data will be fetched and shown in my application . I have done this with JS API but still confused b/w the two.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Both are same if you want to use JS API then you may include js code in your code otherwise you can use OAUTH, Both methods are fetching same fields.

If you want to use JS API you can refer these links-
http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2013/05/get-linkedin-logged-in-user.html

for OAUTH - http://mvcrocksonasp.net/OAuthWithMVC4

get code from these links.